# Convert a d3 chart to load data from json inside a variable

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, bar-chart, loaddata

I'm trying to make a bar chart with d3, and for this I'm following this tutorial [d3noob chart](http://www.d3noob.org/2014/02/making-bar-chart-in-d3js.html), everything looks good but I'm unable to load the data from a JSON inside a variable instead of load from a JSON file, i've managed to load the json to a var but I have no idea of how to iterate the data and create the bars. The code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
    <style>

        .axis {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
        }

        .axis path,
        .axis line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #000;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

    <script>



        var jdata =  [
        {
            "date": "2013-01",
            "value": "53"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-02",
            "value": "165"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-03",
            "value": "269"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-04",
            "value": "344"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-05",
            "value": "376"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-06",
            "value": "410"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-07",
            "value": "421"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-08",
            "value": "405"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-09",
            "value": "376"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-10",
            "value": "359"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-11",
            "value": "392"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-12",
            "value": "433"
        },
        {
            "date": "2014-01",
            "value": "455"
        },
        {
            "date": "2014-02",
            "value": "478"
        }
        ];

        // console.log(jdata);
        root = JSON.parse( jdata );

        var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
        width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m").parse;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);

var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom")
.tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y-%m"));

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left")
.ticks(10);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.data(root)
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//d3.json

//d3.csv("bar-data.csv", function(error, data) {
//d3.selectAll('g').data(function(data){


    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.value = +d.value;
    });

    x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

    svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", "-.55em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

    svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Value ($)");

    svg.selectAll("bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .style("fill", "steelblue")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

});


</script>

</body>
```

It's here too: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bigua/gwtytyks/).

Comment: A couple of things to think about... 1. why are you parsing jdata?  2. where have you declared `data` prior to `data.forEach(function(d) {...`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See my comments in the code...

```
    var jdata = [
    {
        "date": "2013-01",
        "value": "53"
    },
    {
        "date": "2013-02",
        "value": "165"
    },
    {
        "date": "2013-03",
        "value": "269"
    },
    {
        "date": "2013-04",
        "value": "344"
    },
    {
        "date": "2013-05",
        "value": "376"
    },
    {
        "date": "2013-06",
        "value": "410"
    },
    {
        "date": "2013-07",
        "value": "421"
    },
    {
        "date": "2013-08",
        "value": "405"
    },
    {
        "date": "2013-09",
        "value": "376"
    },
    {
        "date": "2013-10",
        "value": "359"
    },
    {
        "date": "2013-11",
        "value": "392"
    },
    {
        "date": "2013-12",
        "value": "433"
    },
    {
        "date": "2014-01",
        "value": "455"
    },
    {
        "date": "2014-02",
        "value": "478"
    }
    ],


    //root = JSON.parse(jdata),
    //***EDIT*** jdata is not a string as required by JSON.parse
    //it's already well formed so just use it
    data = jdata,

    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom,

    // Parse the date / time
    //***a better comment would be "for parsing the date and time"...
    parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m").parse,

    x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05),

    y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),

    xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y-%m")),

    yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10),

    svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    //***EDIT***
    //the data method returns the enter collection and your not ready for it yet...
    //.data(root)
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    //d3.json

    //d3.csv("bar-data.csv", function(error, data) {
    //d3.selectAll('g').data(function(data){

    data.forEach(function (d) {

        //NOW is parsing the date and time
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);

        d.value = +d.value;
    });

    x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", "-.55em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Value ($)");

    svg.selectAll("bar")
        .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
        .style("fill", "steelblue")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

    //You forgot to comment this out...
//        });

</script>
```