# how to load a json object instead of json file

Tags: json, d3.js

I am trying to build a web project where I get details in JSON format, for example:

```
{
    "file_id": 333, 
    "t": "2016-03-08 12:00:56"
}
```

I was trying to show the output in d3 js bar chart. The problem I am facing is the code I've got is working for a JSON file but not for an object deserialized from the JSON. Can any one help me out with this?

The part of the working script for JSON file is this:

```
d3.json("FILENAME", function(error, data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency })]);
```

If I change the filename to an object its not working.

Comment: Erm... How is this Java?

Comment: read the documentation here https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests

it clearly states you have to give a path to file, the function is not made to take an object

Comment: ys , but how can i proceed if i have a json object

Comment: have your tried this example >> https://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/3HL4a/13/

Comment: Check this >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618805/convert-a-d3-chart-to-load-data-from-json-inside-a-variable

Answer (score 28, accepted):

being a JS library D3 works with the JS objects(along with other JS data types) only, `d3.json` is just a method to load the object from an external file. So if you dont need to load data from external file then dont use `d3.json`

```
//d3.json("FILENAME", function(error, data) {
    //data = JSON.parse(data);
    var data = {
        "file_id": 333, 
        "t": "2016-03-08 12:00:56"
    }; //your own object
    x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.file_id}));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.t})]);
```

hope it helps

Comment: What about pulling the json data from a cookie?  I pulled the json data from a cookie to a variable, but cannot get my graph to update using the d3.json function.  It appears from this answer that one cannot do this with the d3.json function.  Can you use the function and pull the data from a cookie, or just a file only?

Comment: It doesn't matter from where and how you pull the data. in the end its all about passing required data to d3 methods. If you need to fetch it from a file use d3.json, otherwise it's not required.
It will be better if you can provide some code about how you are doing it, otherwise it's hard to guess what's the problem you are facing. a jsfiddle or any similar service link to your code will be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> *If I change the filename to an object its not working.*

Then you should call it in a function and pass the object in the params:

```
var obj = {}; // the object to be be passed for chart

function updateGraph(o){ // get in the params here
    var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width]),
        y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

    x.domain(o.letter);
    y.domain([0, o.frequency]);
}

updateGraph(obj); // <----pass it here
```