# Upload a JSON file to slate or foundry

Tags: palantir-foundry

Is there any way to load an external JSON file into the foundry or slate without it being modified and call it in the code sandbox?

I tried to upload a simple JSON file to try to call it inside the code sandbox, but every time I upload the file into the foundry it looks like this

[image: Uploaded JSON]

And inside this file there is nothing

[image: Inside uploaded JSON]

But in the original file, it has a content

[image: content inside json]

PS: Every time I uploaded the json file to the foundry I used the option - "Upload as a raw file without modifying the extension (recommended)"

[image: option]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative, given it is not "uploading the file", strictly speaking.

You can paste the content of your JSON in a [Slate's function](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/slate/concepts-functions/), like :

```json
    return [
        {
            "mykey": "myvalue"
        },
        {
            "mykey": "myvalue"
        }
    ]
```

The JSON will then be available in Slate by calling `{{f_function}}` if `f_function` is the name of your function.

For usage in Code-Sandbox, you can pass it via the [interaction tab of Code-Sandbox](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/slate/widgets-advanced/#interactions-tab).

Like:

```json
    {
      "myjson": {{f_function}}
    }
```

You can then use `SlateFunctions.getState` in Code-Sandbox's JS to fetch the JSON, as the docs describe.

Another flavor: store your file in a [Functions Code Repository](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/functions/use-functions/) and then [call it from Slate](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/slate/ontology-functions/) which essentially leads to the same structure to pass it to CodeSandbox, but with `{{ff_foundry_function}}` instead of `{{f_function}}`.

Comment: Yes, I tried to do that before I asked the question, but the library I'm using strictly requires a JSON file as parameter, but anyway I thank you for answering

Comment: What is the library ? Which function do you try to call ? Does it need a path to a file ?  There might be some way to "emulate" the file (e.g. Blobs, etc.)

Comment: I am using a lib called d3.js and the function is d3.json(), I have been researching ways to bypass it, and will try with JSON.parse()

Comment: To what I see (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35910649/how-to-load-a-json-object-instead-of-json-file) using .json() is not strictly needed. If you have a particular example in mind (which kind of graph are you trying to create?) it should be possible without referencing a file :)

Comment: Thanks man, thanks to the example you linked I made some changes in the code and the graphic appeared on the screen

Comment: Nice. Glad that I could help ! Good luck ! :D